# Joomla: Why is my tmp folder "Unwritable"?

Tags: httpd, joomla

We have here a new installed and setup CentOS7 system with a new Joomla installation. I'm wondering about that all Joomla files are "Unwritable":

If we open in Joomla "System" - "System Information" - "Folder Permissions" there are all folders listed as "Unwritable"

The folder on the disk are all own by user "apache" and are all writable for the user:

```
[root@localhost joomla]# ls -la
insgesamt 88
drwxr-xr-x. 18 apache apache  4096 12. Nov 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 apache root      19 11. Nov 18:03 ..
drwxr-x--x. 10 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 administrator
drwxr-x--x.  2 apache apache    42 21. Okt 23:48 bin
drwxr-x--x.  2 apache apache    23 21. Okt 23:48 cache
drwxr-x--x.  2 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 cli
drwxr-x--x. 16 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 components
-rw-------.  1 apache root    1902 12. Nov 12:50 configuration.php
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache  2915 21. Okt 23:48 htaccess.txt
drwxr-x--x.  5 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 images
drwxr-x--x.  2 apache apache    61 21. Okt 23:48 includes
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache  1212 21. Okt 23:48 index.php
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache  1872 22. Okt 15:55 joomla.xml
drwxr-x--x.  4 apache apache    51 21. Okt 23:48 language
drwxr-x--x.  5 apache apache    66 21. Okt 23:48 layouts
drwxr-x--x. 11 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 libraries
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache 18092 21. Okt 23:48 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-x--x.  2 apache apache    23 21. Okt 23:48 logs
drwxr-x--x. 18 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 media
drwxr-x--x. 27 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 modules
drwxr-x--x. 14 apache apache  4096 21. Okt 23:48 plugins
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache  4213 21. Okt 23:48 README.txt
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache   842 21. Okt 23:48 robots.txt.dist
drwxr-x--x.  5 apache apache    64 21. Okt 23:48 templates
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache    23 21. Okt 23:48 tmp
-rwxr-x--x.  1 apache apache  1690 21. Okt 23:48 web.config.txt
```

Also httpd is running with apache user:

```
[root@localhost joomla]# ps aux | grep httpd
root      8642  0.0  1.2 396684 13032 ?        Ss   13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8644  0.0  0.7 396684  7316 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8645  0.0  0.7 396684  7784 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8646  0.0  1.3 502324 13332 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8647  0.0  0.7 396684  7784 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8648  0.0  1.3 502324 13332 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8650  0.0  1.3 502324 13332 ?        S    13:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8651  0.0  0.6 396684  6588 ?        S    13:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    8652  0.0  0.7 396684  7784 ?        S    13:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root      8660  0.0  0.0 112660   924 pts/0    R+   13:27   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

Why are the folder's not writable?!?

Comment: what are the permissions of the folders that are before your joomla directory ?

Comment: check your configuration.php for the location of the configured tmp directory, perhaps it's not in your documentroot; I always configure it to be out of reach e.g. one level back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I found the problem. After installing CentOS, I have disable SELinux without doing a reboot. After reboot the machine the folder(s) are writeable :-)

Of course: alternativly I can also add a SELinux rule for allowing write access to the specific dirs ...